# Where to store the user credentials in an Angular application?

Tags: angular

The angular client application is running on `http://localhost:4200`

It communicates with a Spring based Restful API running on `http://localhost:8080`
The authentication mechanism at backend is `http basic`, and for every request Spring internally invokes a filter to check the authenticity of the credentials passed from the Angular client when a user logs in.

When a user logs in, his/her credentials are encoded with `Base64.encodeBase64`
and set into the `Authorization` header.

```
private getHeaders(){

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization','Basic ' + btoa("bill:abc123"));
    return headers;
}
```

The btoa function is used to set the `Authorization` header. This works great and `TLS/ HTTPS` will be used to encrypt the credentials to securely pass over the network.

For subsequent request, I need to pass the same credentials every time. So, where should I store the user credentials, once he/she has logged in successfully for subsequent requests?

For example, this request:

```
addEmployee( employee : Employee ) : Observable<Response> {
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/employee/', JSON.stringify(employee),
            {headers: this.getHeaders()}).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: A cookie, or LocalStorage. But storing a password is really not a good idea. A token (such as a JWT token or a session token) would be much safer.

Comment: @JBNizet: But the http basic authentication mechanism at backend expects the username and password every time.

Comment: Well... change the backend.

Comment: @JBNizet: You mean get rid of the http basic mechanism.

Comment: No, not necessarily. You can keep supporting it, and support an additional token-based mechanism.

Comment: Use a service to get user credentials `UserService`, store it in local storage or in memory as you wish, but yeah you cant store a *password* as plain text for obvious reasons. Create a `HttpInterceptor` to add headers to all requests, and use the user service in the interceptor to get the token.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About storing you have 3 ways.

## `localStorage`

`localStorage` is storing `key` and a string `value`. It won't be wiped after closing browser.

```
// setting new item
localStorage.setItem('MyApp_Auth', JSON.stringify(obj));

// getting item
let auth;
if (localStorage.getItem('MyApp_Auth')
   auth = localStorage.getItem('MyApp_Auth');

// removing
localStorage.removeItem('MyApp_Auth');

// clear all data
localStorage.clear();
```

## `sessionStorage`

`sessionStorage` is similiar to `localStorage`, but its data is only kept as long as session is not closed. Usage is exatcly the same as `localStorage`.

## Cookies

Cookies are a bit more problematic since it's only

```
document.cookies = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

So it's hard to maintain because it's only one string separated with `;`, so to use it the best option is 3rd party library. Something like [js-cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)  or more angular friendly [angular2-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie);

## `HttpInterceptor`

Since version 4 of Angular you can implement `HttpInterceptor` in which you can automaticaly add `headers` to your every `request`. For more information, read [Authenticaion using the HttpClient and HttpInterceptors](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8).